# Call passport.authenticate('local') directly from the Server

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, passport.js, passport-local

The passport.authenticate documentation specifies the following post request which can be used to initiate an authentication process using the local strategy.

```
 app.post('/login', passport.authenticate('local'), function(req, res) {
   res.send(res.userName)
 })
```

I would like to be able to launch this same request directly from the server, without being initiated by the client. How can I make this call directly from the server?

Comment: By "launch this same request directly from the server", do you mean that you want your server to be able to send a HTTP request to `/login` route without having to do local authentication?

Comment: Thank you Owl. Actually, I mean call the code within this request as if it were a regular function. I have tried to modify it as a function (passing it the proper parameters), but I am having difficulty making it work properly. This function triggers other functions, as you may know, and I am able to make it work when a request is made from the client, but because of my specific application, I do not need to make this request from the client side, but wish to call a function from the server side which will execute code similar to what is included in the passport library. J